# What is the appropriate CAN interface string to use in ctre phoenix's ctre::phoenix::platform::can::SetCANInterface function

Tags: c++, can-bus

I'm trying to use ctre's phoenix library with a Talon SRX and CANable Pro.  What I have worked in Ubuntu, as a simple "can0" was the appropriate argument.  I'm now trying to use it in Windows 10 with the same code (and correct Windows dependencies), but it won't connect to the Talon.  I've verified the talon's device ID, so I'm 90% sure it's simply the argument in the setCANInterface function, though I could very well be wrong.  Here's the code...

```
  TalonSRX talon = 2;

  ctre::phoenix::platform::can::SetCANInterface("USB\Class_02&SubClass_02&Prot_01");

  talon.Set(ControlMode::PercentOutput, 1);
  
  while(true)
  {
  
    ctre::phoenix::unmanaged::Unmanaged::FeedEnable(100);
  }
```

Comment: `"USB\C` isn't valid C++, use `"USB\\C`

Comment: You are absolutely right with the \\, I guess that isn't the right string still.  I must need an entirely different device string.